# References not deployed when using ResolveReferences and _CopyWebApplication in AfterBuild

Tags: asp.net, deployment, msbuild

The following MSBuild invocation works great when used in an independent MSBuild project, LocalPublish.xml.

```
<MSBuild
Projects="MyProject.Web.csproj"
Targets="ResolveReferences;_CopyWebApplication"
Properties="WebProjectOutputDir=C:\Inetpub\MyProject\Website;OutDir=C:\Inetpub\MyProject\Website\bin\" />
```

In the past, we have invoked it using a Post-build event command line:
$(MSBuildBinPath)\msbuild "$(ProjectDir)LocalPublish.xml"

However I'm now trying to integrate the same into the AfterBuild event of MyProject.Web.csproj, and it fails to copy referenced project DLLs into the bin folder of the publish path. I tried adding BuildingProject=true to the Properties attribute as suggested [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/383199/resolvereferences-does-not-correctly-walk-all-references-in-dependent-projects#details) but it does not seem to make a difference.